# Set current tab active after file upload in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net

I have 3 tabs, for which in second tab there is a file upload option. Currently what happening is after file upload completes the page refreshes and it goes to the first tab. But I want to stay in the current tab where the file was uploaded successfully.

HTML

```
<ul class="navTabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#c_vendorData" rel="#c_vendorData" aria-controls="vendor data" role="tab"><i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>Vendor Data</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#c_upload" rel="#c_upload" aria-controls="upload" role="tab"><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>Upload</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#c_config" rel="#c_config" aria-controls="configuration" role="tab"><i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i>Configuration</a></li>
    <span class="active-marker"></span>
</ul>
```

File upload HTML code

```
<div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <asp:FileUpload ID="IPFEEBtn" class="form-control" runat="server" name="IPFEEBtn" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 filterButton">
            <div class="form-group">


                <asp:Button ID="UploadBtn" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="UploadBtn_Click" CssClass="btn button" />
                <asp:Button ID="IPFEEDownloadbtn" runat="server" Text="Download Format" OnClick="IPFEEDownloadbtn_Click" CssClass="btn button white" />

            </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--end config-->
```

How to make it active in second tab after file upload?

**UPDATE**

```html
 <!--upload-->
                <div id="c_upload" role="tabpanel" class="tabPane upload">
                    <div class="panelContent">
                        <div class="filter">
                            <div class="fLeft">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <asp:FileUpload ID="IPFEEBtn" class="form-control" runat="server" name="IPFEEBtn" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6 filterButton">
                                        <div class="form-group">


                                            <asp:Button ID="UploadBtn" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="UploadBtn_Click" CssClass="btn button" />
                                            <asp:Button ID="IPFEEDownloadbtn" runat="server" Text="Download Format" OnClick="IPFEEDownloadbtn_Click" CssClass="btn button white" />

                                        </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="fRight"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="datatableGrid">
                            <div class="dt_content">
                                <div class="dt_tables">
                                    <div class="iptable table-responsive">
                                        
                                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upNeInvReportGridView" runat="server">
                                            <ContentTemplate>
                                                <asp:GridView ID="grdStructId" EditRowStyle-Wrap="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="5" CssClass="table dataTable dtTable table-bordered nowrap pageResize" runat="server"
                                                    >
                                                    <Columns>
                                                        <%--<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <asp:Label ID="IPFEEId" Text='<%# Bind("ID") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                    </asp:TemplateField>--%>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SAP_ID">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="IPFEESAPID" Text='<%# Bind("SAP_ID") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CITY">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="IPFEECITY" Text='<%# Bind("CITY") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FINAL_SR_DATE">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="IPFEEFINALSRDATE" Text='<%# Bind("FINAL_SR_DATE") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FINAL_SO_DATE">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="IPFEEFINALSODATE" Text='<%# Bind("FINAL_SO_DATE") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="INVOICE_DATE">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="IPFEEINVOICEDATE" Text='<%# Bind("INVOICE_DATE") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="IP_ID">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="IPFEEIPID" Text='<%# Bind("IP_ID") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="APPLICABLE_MSA">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="IPFEEAPPLICABLEMSA" Text='<%# Bind("APPLICABLE_MSA") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SITE_CATEOGRY">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="IPFEESITECATEOGRY" Text='<%# Bind("SITE_CATEOGRY") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <%--<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID_OD">
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <asp:Label ID="IPFEEIDOD" Text='<%# Bind("ID_OD") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                    </asp:TemplateField>--%>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID_OD">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="IPFEEIDOD" Text='<%# Bind("ID_OD") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RFI_DATE">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="IPFEERFIDATE" Text='<%# Bind("RFI_DATE") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="BILL_START_DATE">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="IPFEEBILLSTARTDATE" Text='<%# Bind("BILL_START_DATE") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="BILL_END_DATE">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="IPFEEBILLENDDATE" Text='<%# Bind("BILL_END_DATE") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="NO_OF_OPCO">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="IPFEENOOFOPCO" Text='<%# Bind("NO_OF_OPCO") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ACTUAL_RENT_AMT">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="IPFEEACTUALRENTAMT" Text='<%# Bind("ACTUAL_RENT_AMT") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TENURE">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="IPFEETENURE" Text='<%# Bind("TENURE") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="GSM_ANTENNA_EXC_SAIL">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="IPFEEGSMANTENNAEXCSAIL" Text='<%# Bind("GSM_ANTENNA_EXC_SAIL") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="GSM_ANTENNA_NOTEXC_SAIL">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="IPFEEGSMANTENNANOTEXCSAIL" Text='<%# Bind("GSM_ANTENNA_NOTEXC_SAIL") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="REV_TOT_CNT_GSM_ANTENNA">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="IPFEEREVTOTCNTGSMANTENNA" Text='<%# Bind("REV_TOT_CNT_GSM_ANTENNA") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MW_ANTENNA_OF_UPTO06_DIA">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="IPFEEMWANTENNAOFUPTO06DIA" Text='<%# Bind("MW_ANTENNA_OF_UPTO06_DIA") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MW_ANTENNA_OF_12DIA">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="IPFEEMWANTENNAOF12DIA" Text='<%# Bind("MW_ANTENNA_OF_12DIA") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MW_ANTENNA_OF_GREATER12_DIA">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="IPFEEMWANTENNAOFGREATER12DIA" Text='<%# Bind("MW_ANTENNA_OF_GREATER12_DIA") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="HEIGHT_OF_HEIGHEST_ANTENNA">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="IPFEEHEIGHTOFHEIGHESTANTENNA" Text='<%# Bind("HEIGHT_OF_HEIGHEST_ANTENNA") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="WEIGHT_OF_TOWER_TOP_BTS">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="IPFEEWEIGHTOFTOWERTOPBTS" Text='<%# Bind("WEIGHT_OF_TOWER_TOP_BTS") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="WIND_SPEED">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="IPFEEWINDSPEED" Text='<%# Bind("WIND_SPEED") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="POWER_RATING_OF_BTS">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="IPFEEPOWERRATINGOFBTS" Text='<%# Bind("POWER_RATING_OF_BTS") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FLOOR_SPACE_INDOOR">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="IPFEEFLOORSPACEINDOOR" Text='<%# Bind("FLOOR_SPACE_INDOOR") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FLOOR_SPACE_OUTDOOR">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="IPFEEFLOORSPACEOUTDOOR" Text='<%# Bind("FLOOR_SPACE_OUTDOOR") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="EB_STATUS_VALUE">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="IPFEEEBSTATUSVALUE" Text='<%# Bind("EB_STATUS_VALUE") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="NO_OF_US">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="IPFEENOOFUS" Text='<%# Bind("NO_OF_US") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="HIGHER_RENT">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="IPFEHIGHERRENT" Text='<%# Bind("HIGHER_RENT") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RRH_COUNT">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="IPFERRHCOUNT" Text='<%# Bind("RRH_COUNT") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="VOLUME_DISCOUNT">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="IPFEVOLUMEDISCOUNT" Text='<%# Bind("VOLUME_DISCOUNT") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="VENDOR_NAME">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="IPFEEVENDORNAME" Text='<%# Bind("VENDOR_NAME") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CIRCLE">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="IPFEECIRCLE" Text='<%# Bind("CIRCLE") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="APPLICABLE_SITE_RENT">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="IPFEEAPPLICABLESITERENT" Text='<%# Bind("APPLICABLE_SITE_RENT") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <%--<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="LAST_UPDATED_DATE">
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <asp:Label ID="IPFEELASTUPDATEDDATE" Text='<%# Bind("LAST_UPDATED_DATE") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                    </asp:TemplateField>--%>
                                                    </Columns>

                                                    <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="right" CssClass="GridPager" />
                                                    <EditRowStyle Wrap="True" />
                                                    <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                                        No Record Found
                                                    </EmptyDataTemplate>
                                                </asp:GridView>
                                            </ContentTemplate>

                                            <Triggers>
                                                <%--   <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="bSearch" EventName="Click" />--%>
                                                <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="bExportToExcel" />
                                                <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="UploadBtn" />

                                            </Triggers>
                                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="dt_footer">
                                    <asp:Button ID="bExportToExcel" runat="server" Text="Export To Excel" OnClick="bExportToExcel_Click" CssClass="btn button" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--end upload-->
```

Comment: Hi, which bootstrap version are you using and always second tab will be open ?

Comment: @Swati: not always..how to get bootstrap version ?

Comment: You must have  added cdn for bootstrap there you will see there . `src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap..` so here bootstrap version is 3.3.7 .

Answer (score 3):

Based on the provided HTML and code, you can achieve this by JavaScript. Try the below code:

```
<script>
        $(function () {
            var elementObject = localStorage.getItem('active');

            if (elementObject) {
                var element = JSON.parse(elementObject);
                $('.navTabs').children().removeClass("active");
                $('.navTabs').children().eq(parseInt(element.index)).addClass('active');
                window.location.hash = element.id;
            }
        });

        $(document).on('click', '.navTabs li', function () {
            debugger;
            $('.navTabs li').removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
            var obj = { index: $(this).index(), id: $(this).children()[0].rel };
            localStorage.setItem('active', JSON.stringify(obj));
        });

 </script>
```

Explanation: On clicking the **ul** item we're saving the clicked one **li** element to an object with its id and on page load, we're retrieving it and setting it again to the previous/saved state.

Comment: @hud Let me check!

Comment: @hud I ran your code & it's working fine. Can you please tell me what steps you are following?

Comment: @hud join this: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234254/room-for-arib-yousuf-and-hud